# Bourne shell: ignoring certain kinds of stdin

Tags: regular-expression, stdin, bourne-shell

I have a program that is currently working, but I need to modify it to ignore some stdin that is not fitting for its correct function.

Right now, to run the program:
printf "1\n3\n5\n" | sh prog

The program currently ignores non-integer input (like floats), but **I also need it to ignore something like '4 10' on the same line and '5 text' etc.**

```
#! /bin/sh

sum=0;  
cnt=0

while read line
do

   case "$line" in

        *[.]*  )   #------I think here is where the regex needs to be edited
            printf "\n0"
            continue
            ;;

        [0-9]* )
            sum=`expr "$sum" + "$line"`
           cnt=`expr "$cnt" + 1`
            printf "\n%s" `expr $sum / $cnt`
            ;;
    esac

done
```

I'm pretty sure it's just a matter of changing the regex on the line I pointed out so that it goes to the print 0 and continue case with the two non-desired input types I described above but I am having trouble with it.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you make `[0-9]* )` as first condition, then make the second condition `*)` to catch all other thing.

Comment: Shell case patterns are not regular expressions; they are more like shell globs. The pattern `*[.]*` means anything or nothing followed by a single character followed by anything or nothing. I'm pretty sure that' not what you intended.

Comment: if you're using GNU Bash, you can get regex matching with `[[ $foo ~= pattern ]]` (see the man page).  With `shopt -s extglob`, you can use things like `foo.@(zip|7z)` in glob expressions.  (also ?, *, +, and ! operators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do...

```
while read line
do    line=${line%%[!0-9]*}
      [ -n "$line" ] || continue
      : work w/ digits at line's head
done
```

Alternatively - and probably faster - you can do:

```
tr -cs 0-9\\n \ |
while IFS=\  read num na
do    ${num:+":"} continue
      : work w/ first seq of digits on line
done
```

Or is if you want to ignore *completely* any line containing anything but spaces, tabs, or numbers, or even any line containing two space-separated nums...

```
b=${IFS%?}
grep "^[$b]*[0-9]\{1,\}[$b]*$" |
while read num; do : stuff with "$num"; done
```

With `case` you could do it like this:

```
while read num
do    case ${num:--} in 
      *[!0-9]*) continue;;esac
      : something w/ $num
done
```

Comment: I implemented the last version of your solution to my code and the problem is that it only prints a zero in the place of an incorrect input once, not for each case.

Comment: @user3295764 - Oh, yeah, you really need the zeroes? Ok.

Comment: Actually, I figured out adding printf statements, but the bigger issue is that it should support negative numbers

Comment: and integers that have just one space like ' 20' and '2 '

Comment: @user329574 - ok, we can do that, but in that case can I use `grep` or `sed` - they're bound to be *way* faster than a shell `while read; case ... in` loop - that's slow, man. About the blanks though - there won't be *any* of those - because the shell's `$IFS` eats them at head and tail of line.

Comment: Yea, that's cool as long as I can still apply it to the desired function of the program.

Comment: Actually, no worries, figured it out

Comment: pure bash text processing is actually not that slow.  The bash-completion code does a LOT with bash >= 4.1 built-in stuff.  You can write faster code if you take advantage of stuff like bash regexes, arrays, and text match/replace.  And stuff like `printf -v var` instead of `var=$(echo ...)` There's also a `readarray` builtin, useful if you know your input isn't huge.  But even a `while read` loop isn't terrible.  On small problem sizes, working in pure bash saves the cost of the fork, exec, and everything the dynamic linker does at process startup, which offsets the advantage of `sed` etc.

Comment: @PeterCordes - `bash` is slow at basically everything it does - *especially* regexps and reads. Generally, if you're looking to save a fork, it's better to start a pipeline and follow a single stream in a chain. Try, for example, `time seq 1000000 | grep -F 000 >/dev/null` and compare the results to `seq 1000000 | bash -c 'while IFS= read -r line; do case $line in *000*) printf %s\\n "$line";; esac; done' >/dev/null`. For me the difference is .025 seconds vs 21 seconds. `bash` doesn't save much at all - and is really not even a very good shell as shells go.

Comment: Hmm, yeah you're right, it's dog-slow even without the loop body.  My mistake.  bash-completion usually works with small data sets; loops that might run 10 times or so.  The conventional wisdom is that for problem sizes that small, it's worth avoiding the startup time of an external tool if it doesn't take much code.  (bash-completion uses grep and sed all over the place, but rarely awk, and never perl (at least not just for text processing).)

Comment: Leaving out IFS unset makes that loop 4x faster, BTW.  It still reads in 128B `read(2)` system calls, when redirected from a file, so it's hilariously inefficient.  (and it makes an `ioctl` and 2 `lseek`s for each 128B chunk.)  from a pipe, it's even worse: one character at a time, with an `ioctl` and `lseek` after every newline.